# Is it possible to sync notifications across multiple desktops with StackApplet?

Tags: feature-request, stackapplet

These days people usually work on a number of machines, laptop for the road, desktop at home, perhaps even a machine at work or uni.  This creates the need to have notifications synced somehow.  It is difficult to keep track of notifications because stackapplet is always displaying outdated notifications on one or the other of my machines.

Comment: not to be esoteric, but i'm working on that problem ;)

Comment: @George Edison would be pleased to hear.  He was interested on implementation ideas, so maybe you would like to run your ideas by him at some point. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment - **but** because this has affected me too (moving back and forth between systems running StackApplet) I am considering putting something like this into the planning stages.

The important thing to realize here is that the API is read-only at the moment, and as such dismissing any notifications using the API is impossible. My solution would need to involve some form of third-party synchronization, likely involving setting up an account on my website and then signing in to it with each installation of StackApplet.

Any feedback on how such a system would be set up and implemented is appreciated.

Comment: Any progress on this feature so far George? How about you @Patrick Perini ?

Comment: @ptrcao: A new version of the API will be released before the end of the year, so we'll have a better idea then.